# logout and update mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to disconnect a user by clicking on a button, and at the time of this click, record in a mySQL database the score of the player, which was until then in a session variable.
Knowing that the disconnection can be done like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = [];
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../../index.php');
```

I tried to do this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('actions/database.php');
$updateScore = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET score=? WHERE id=?");
$updateScore->execute(array($_SESSION['score'], $_SESSION['id']));

$_SESSION = [];
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../../index.php');
```

but it's not working :/

I'm a totally beginner in these languages so this question is probably very silly, sorry in advance.
thanks for reading :)

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` before you read from and/or write to the session variables. Right now, you're trying to read the values from the session before it's started.

Comment: I've tried and it's not working with `session_start()` at the beginning, but it's probably far better than my version

Comment: It's not just "probably far better", it's required for you to be able the read the session values at all. If it still doesn't work, then there's more than one issue. Have you dumped the values `$_SESSION['score']` and `$_SESSION['id']` to check that they contain what you expect? Check the web servers error log for errors. Also add some proper [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to your queries. You should also expand on what "not working" means. Explain in detail what happens. Wrong data? Nothing? Do you have output before this code? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I've found the error in the servers log, it is apparently a problem of path because I get this : **PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'actions/database.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.16/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/seio/actions/users/logoutAction.php on line 3** but it's strange because I use the same line in another file in the same directory and it's working well

Comment: When requiring files like you are, the path will be relative from the entry php file. Edit the question to include the error message, the file and folder structure of your app (relevant files) and explain what the URL is (what the entry PHP file is).

Comment: I've finally found the problem, just a path issue, thanks for your time !